# Does Spotify support Windows Phone?

Tags: apps

I've heard that Windows Phone lacks a lot of apps. Do Spotify have a Windows Phone app?

Comment: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/search?q=spotify

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, Spotify is available in the [Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=10f2995d-1f82-4203-b7fa-46ddbd07a6e6).

[image: A screenshot of the Spotify app]